# Matlab loops for a function

Tags: matlab, function, loops, iteration, mean

I am trying to make a loop to redo a Matlab function 1000 times. Here's the program

```
d = unifrnd (0,10,[10,1]);
c = d.^(-2);
a = round(unifrnd(0,1,[1,10]);
e = a*c
btotal = e+1
SIR = 1/btotal
```

What I want is to iterate this function 1000 times, each time the value of SIR will vary due to the random number generated. For every iteration, I want the value of SIR to be added together (summed up), and in the end of the 1000th iteration, find the average SIR(mean).

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, is this homework? What have you tried and into what problems did you run?

Comment: Heys, thanks for the response, its not homework, im just doing a communications project with a friend and we need to simulate the signal to interference ratio of a wireless network. Im quite new to Matlab so I dont know exactly how to implement the loops and modify it exactly to what i need it to do as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below implements what you described:

#### genSIR.m

```
function SIR = genSIR()
    d = unifrnd (0,10,[10,1]);
    c = d.^(-2);
    a = round(unifrnd(0,1,[1,10]));
    e = a*c;
    btotal = e+1;
    SIR = 1/btotal;
end
```

#### main program

```
N = 1000;
SIR = zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
    SIR(i) = genSIR();
end
s = sum(SIR)
m = mean(SIR)
```

although your function could be simplified...

Comment: amazing answer, but How can i return values from a function ? example: the function will do calculation and return 3 variables back to me (array variables)