# matlab store multiple outputs of function from loop in matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, output, store

i am trying to save the output of the following function (it gives two outputs for every iteration of input 1, the rest remains the same).

The function creates a stress testing for an interbank market, testing for the effects (output is capital_losses and defaulted_banks) of default of every bank in the sample, i.e. input1 must go from 1:(length(input2), 4 in the code provided here, 300+ in the final code, so i need a loop

here a sample of one iteration with bank 3 defaulting

```
input1 = 3; % default_bank
input2=[100000;200000;300000;400000]; % capital levels in the function
input3 = ...
 [70000, 15000, 24000, 52453; 
  23420, 24252, 10000, 35354; 
  98763, 45666, 96555, 05000; 
  09800, 54444, 04336, 67520]; % interbank loans in the function
input4 = 1; 
input5 = .35; 
input6 = 1; 
% function calls on above inputs
[capital_losses defaulted_banks] = interbank_model( ...
input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6)
```

this is the standard output for one iteration with default_bank=3, but I need this for 300+,   so a loop would be helpful...

```
capital_losses3 =
1.0e+05 *
     0.5857
     0.2598
     3.0000
     0.0609


defaulted_banks3 =
     0 
     0
     1
     0
```

I would like to get the output for every defaulted bank, i.e. default_bank=1:4 to be displayed by the for loop as follows:
capital_losses_all =

1.0e+05 *

```
1.0000    0.2320    0.5857    0.5857
0.2867    2.0000    0.2598    0.2598
1.0716    0.4917    3.0000    3.0000
0.2816    0.6682    0.0609    0.0609
```

defaulted_banks_all =

```
 1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1
```

This was manually generated, but how do i store the values in matrices? 
Thanks for your help. (I had a similar question before but the editing and commenting got very confusing so here's my improved cry for help... ) 
Chris

Comment: Take a look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894978/matlab-loops-for-a-function) - maybe it gets you thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Also, I would reply something *very* similar to the [answer you got on your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394737/matlab-for-loop-function-multiple-output-in-matrix/23413336#23413336). If that is not for you, please consider how you could rephrase the question (sounds difficult, but after reading both your questions, and the answer, I still can't figure out why that wouldn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Very general answer (adapt for your need):

```
valuesThatChange = [1 3 5 4 2]; % different for each iteration in the loop
% values that don't change:
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;

N = numel(valuesThatChange);
% create storage for results:
results = zeros(4, N);

% loop N times
for ii=1:N
  results(:,ii) = functionCall(valuesThatChange(ii), a, b, c); % returns a 4 element result
end
```

Now you have the result from your function for each loop in a 4xN matrix.